# stored procedure always returns "Process exited" error always

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a table structure similar to the below and trying to get the output as mentioned.

[image]

To acheive this, I written the below PL SQL procedure:

```
     CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Sample_procedure
AS
  TYPE list_of_names_t
    IS TABLE OF emp.emp_index%TYPE;
  processedindexes LIST_OF_NAMES_T := List_of_names_t();
  flag             emp.emp_index%TYPE;
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   emp
    WHERE  Trim(emp_id) = 'AAAAA'
    ORDER  BY last_maint_ts ASC;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.Put('Entered the loop');

    FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
        SELECT emp_index
        INTO   flag
        FROM   emp
        WHERE  emp_id = rec.emp_id
               AND last_maint_ts > rec.last_maint_ts;

        IF flag IS NOT NULL THEN
          processedindexes.extend;

          Processedindexes(processedindexes.last) := flag;

          processedindexes.extend;

          Processedindexes(processedindexes.last) := rec.emp_index;

          dbms_output.Put('The indexes'
                          ||rec.emp_index
                          ||' & '
                          ||flag
                          ||'refer to same emp ID');

          exit;

          dbms_output.Put('received NULL');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

1) Everytime, I run this i get the output as Process exited in sql developer, Any suggestion on this?

***Note:*** I am new to PL SQL programming, please correct me if my approach of solving this is not right.

Comment: @lc. Thanks so much for formatting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open sqlplus and execute the following :-

```
set serveroutput on
exec Sample_procedure;
```

provided your procedure is compiling fine, it should display the output in dbms_output.put

Comment: Max, Thanks for the answer, I am not seeing any output but it compiles fine without any errors, can you please advice?

Comment: Is there any type of output that you can see in sqlplus (after executing the above) ?

Comment: Is it possible to change the first dbms_output.put to dbms_output.put_line and then execute the above steps again? (not sure if it will do any change but worth a shot). I read that put is considered obsolete now.
http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_output.html

Comment: Thanks so much, It is working now..I am closing this question.